# Still getting gem not found with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to configure my deployment with capistrano for a few weeks now, and it still is not working properly. Every time I deploy to my server I get an error saying a gem is missing, like:

```
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    : 
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    Could not find ansi-1.4.3 in any of the sources
DEBUG [a0e618f0]     (
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    Bundler::GemNotFound
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    )
```

I know how to fix this, simply install the "ansi" gem, but there is a much bigger problem here: why didn't bundler work properly with capistrano??

When I look higher in the output I see:

```
 INFO [1ee9a88e] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 do bundle --gemfile /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608/Gemfile --path /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/shared/bin --without development test on 54.200.196.1
DEBUG [1ee9a88e] Command: cd /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 do bundle --gemfile /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608/Gemfile --path /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/shared/bin --without development test )
 INFO [1ee9a88e] Finished in 20.132 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [7d1a9e40] Running if test ! -d /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608'" 1>&2; false; fi on 54.200.196.1
DEBUG [7d1a9e40] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [7d1a9e40] Finished in 1.291 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [a0e618f0] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 do rake assets:precompile on 54.200.196.1
DEBUG [a0e618f0] Command: cd /var/www/html/SparkMyInterest/releases/20131122204608 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 do rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    : 
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    Could not find ansi-1.4.3 in any of the sources
DEBUG [a0e618f0]     (
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    Bundler::GemNotFound
DEBUG [a0e618f0]    )
```

Clearly it looks like bundler was run (and successful!). What gives?

Here's my cap file:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

And in my production.rb (I'm deploying with production) at the top I have:

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, "production"
```

Any ideas why bundler isn't working? And/ or why it never seems to install all the required gems?

Thank you a million

Comment: Show us your `Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

I've worked through similar issues with rvm involved (required rvm/capistrano) by providing some additional info to capitrano

```
set :bundle_cmd, '/path/to/project/rvm/bundle'
set :default_shell, :bash
set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, release_path
```

This code was in my stage-specific deploy (e.g., deploy/production.rb).  The issue that I had to work around was that the bundle was installed but to the wrong place; could be what you're facing here as well.

FWIW, rvm/capsitrano also let me specify a shell to use when running certain commands within the deploy script.  For example, I was using the whenever gem to update my crontab and needed the "rvm_shell" (my specific ruby with gemset) to make this happen from capistrano.  The line looks like this:

```
run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec whenever -w -s environment=production", shell: fetch(:rvm_shell)
```

Comment: got DEBUG [db260c6b] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm current )
DEBUG [db260c6b]  bash: /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm: No such file or directory
cap aborted!